# Clang equivalent of controlfp (defind in float.h) in VC++

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-c++, clang

I am in task to convert an existing VCpp project to mobile platform. I need to build the V Cpp files to be compiled against Clang. Now got stuck with the controlfp, which is not defined in float.h of Cpp library for Clang. Any equivalent library function for controlfp in Clang?Kindly advice. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: controlfp is to set the floating point unit control word, does your program really need this?

Comment: @Matt I am compiling the file which is already running in win32. Now trying to compile the file in clang. There I encountered this error. I need to write an alternate to the controlfp which is not defined to the Cpp library in Clang.

Comment: @GovindPN I suspect the program you're porting is very old. Programs usually doesn't need handle floating point exception by this self now, and also this function is related with hardware platform, please read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the reply. My existing win32 application written in Vcpp need to be ported to android. I am getting compiler error when I build the code using Eclipse for Clang compiler. I am now trying to replace it with feenableexept(FE_OVRFLOW)